# Refresh Embedded Chart from Excel in Powerpoint by using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have created the following code but I need to include to refresh the chart that is in Slide 9.

```
    Set oPPApp = CreateObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    With oPPApp
        .Presentations.Open "C:\Users\jmarqu7\Documents\PPT FTL NAR\Carrier Meeting Template - FTL - Test.pptx", Untitled:=msoTrue
        With .ActivePresentation
            .UpdateLinks
            .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\jmarqu7\Documents\PPT FTL NAR\" & NewCat & ".pptx"
            .Close
        End With

    End With
```

Could you please help out which is the command I need to use?

Thanks

Comment: "Embedded" and "linked" are different. You're asking about a linked chart, not an embedded one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Update method of the LinkFormat property of the Shape object.  For example, assuming that pptPres refers to your presentation, and that the chart is located on slide number 9, and that it's called "Chart 1", try...

```
pptPres.Slides(9).Shapes("Chart 1").LinkFormat.Update
```